# Extracting data from Twitter with API

Tags: python, tweepy

I want to extract data from Twitter for a Thesis project.

```
import tweepy
import sys
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import csv
import re
import owslib
from twitter_app_credentials import *
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
        
    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print(status_code)
if(not api):
    print("Authentication failed")
    sys.exit(-1)
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener = myStreamListener)
myStream.filter(track=['news'])
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-194390689c22> in <module>
      1 myStreamListener = MyStreamListener(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
----> 2 myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener = myStreamListener)
      3 myStream.filter(track=['news'])

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'
```

Comment: A stream indeed doesn't take an auth keyword argument (or listener, for that matter): https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/stream.html.

Comment: Thesis project for a PhD?

Comment: It's a Thesis project for a master's degree!

Comment: I'm not a computer scientist, but a management engineer so I'm not specialized in Python. I've found this code on the web and it works, but not in my case. So I don't know how to fix this error!

Comment: first check official documentation for your module - and check if you use the same version. They could change something in different versions - and now it may not use `auth`

Comment: if you found this code on some web then in question you should add url for this page (don't put it in comment). And you should check how old is this page - maybe it is very old post and use uses older version.

Answer (score 0):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) replaced the `auth` parameter for `Stream` with one for each credential.

The `listener` parameter was also removed along with `StreamListener`, as it was merged into `Stream`.

I recommend updating your code, but alternatively, you can downgrade to v3.10.0.